# why this access violation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am getting `access violation` error in the below code..i have pointed it out in the program.

```
void *pBuff = 0;

void set_data(void *pBuff)
{
    int value = 70, i;
    int *phy_bn = new int[8];

    for(i=0; i<8; i++)phy_bn[i] = value;

    pBuff =phy_bn;
    cout<<((int*)pBuff)[0];//..accessing 0th element value..no error here..gives 70 as result..
}


int main()
{
    set_data(pBuff);
    cout<<((int*)pBuff)[0];//acces violation error
    return 0;
}
```

Why that access violation even when i am not assigning it the address of a local variable...

Yes i can use `vector` or `pass by reference`.

But i want to know **why pBuff is not getting assigned**

Comment: You're going to have to pass either a pointer reference or a double pointer if you're expecting to be able to pass a newly created buffer out via a parameter. That's just the way the language works!

Comment: Pass your pointer by reference rather than value. I.e. `void set_data(void*& pBuff)`

Comment: @Rook, @WhozCraig note that `pBuff` is already global. Not necessarily the best way to do it, but they don't need a double pointer in their current setup.

Comment: @Xymostech indeed, which is why I qualified my statement and specifically referred to parameters ;-)

Comment: "i want to avoid double pointers..its not required i guess..." - a double pointer, or a reference to pointer, certainly is required if you want to pass a pointer by reference. Whether you should be doing that (and whether you should be using global variables, manual memory management, and untyped pointers) is an entirely different question.

Comment: Look at the various answers written here. `pBuff` **is** getting assigned, but not outside your function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
pBuff = phy_bn;
```

You're just changing the local value of `pBuff`, not the global value of `pBuff`. Either pass `pBuff` as a double pointer, or simply remove the argument to the function, as `pBuff` is global already.

```
void *pBuff = 0; /* This is the global pBuff, which isn't being changed */

void set_data(void *pBuff /* This is the local pBuff, which is being changed */)
{
    ...
    pBuff = phy_bn;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i wanted to just clear my concept..yes i can use vector or pass by reference..but i want to know why **pBuff is not getting assigned**

Comment: @cSharper because you have both a local version and a global version, and so you're only changing the local version when you do your assignment.

Comment: @cSharper because you are **not passing by reference**!

Comment: If you really meant 'why the global definiton of `pBuff` isn't assigned' this answer really explains it best. The global `pBuff` definition is shadowed by the function parameter with the same name.

Comment: @cSharper It was the last one with all of the information present from the other answers ;o) ...

Answer (score 4):

Because it is a *copy* of the pointer being modified within `set_data()`. Pass the pointer by reference so the change is visible to the caller:

```
void set_data(void*& pBuff)
```

Note that the function variable `pBuff` hides the global variable `pBuff` in the function `set_data()`.

That said, I am unsure of the reason for `void*` and why `vector<int>` is not being used which handles all dynamic memory allocation for you.

Comment: i wanted to just clear my concept..yes i can use vector or pass by reference..but i want to know why **pBuff is not getting assigned**

Answer (score 2):

*'plz i want to avoid double pointers..its not required i guess...'*

Guessed wrong, it **is** required! You'll need a pointer reference for the `pBuff` parameter then:

```
void set_data(void*& pBuff)
{
    // ...
}
```

This is effectively the same as using a double pointer.

The only thing you're doing with

```
pBuff =phy_bn;
```

is manipulating the function parameter representation on the local stack.

Answer (score 0):

The `pBuff` inside `set_data` is not the global `pBuff`. The value of the global `pBuff` never gets changed from 0. Since this is C++ code, `set_data` can take its pointer argument by reference, and assigning to it will change the value at the point of the function call.

Comment: i wanted to just clear my concept..yes i can use vector or pass by reference..but i want to know why **pBuff is not getting assigned**

Answer (score 0):

In C++, pointers are passed *by value*, the same as other value types. It may be instructional to think of a pointer as literally an integer type; then it’s easy to see why `pBuff = phy_bn;` doesn’t accomplish anything, for the same reason that this code doesn’t:

```
#include <iostream>

void set(int x) {
    x = 5;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int y = 0;
    set(y);
    std::cout << y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Here, `x` is a local variable. It is a *copy* of `y`, *not* `y` itself. You can change its value by assigning to it, sure, but you’re merely changing the value of a variable which will not exist outside the scope of `set()`. If you change the definition of `set()` to use a reference:

```
void set(int& x) {
    x = 5;
}
```

Then `y` will indeed be updated, because you have explicitly requested that `x` be an *alias* for the name you pass to `set()`, instead of a copy. You were misled by the names: the `pBuf` in `set_data()` is not the same variable `pBuf` in `main()`, even though they happen to have the same value; they’re like two different people with the same name and the same amount of money.